# Example of a function inlined in another one

Tags: gdb, frame, inline, backtrace

I am debugging a core file using gdb. When I ran backtrace command, i got something like this:

```
#0 0x0056e41e in <<function1>>
#1 0x0057224c in <<function2>>
#2 <<function3>>
#3 0x00580ba4 in <<function4>>
```

So, when i ran info frame on frames 1 and 2 i got:

```
(gdb) info frame 1
Stack frame at 0x2f7cc9c0:
pc = 0x591670 in <<function2>>
saved pc 0x5917fc
inlined into frame 2 [...]

(gdb) info frame 2
Stack frame at 0x2f7cc9c0:
pc = 0x591670 in <<function3>> [...]
```

So, just for educational purposes, how are function2 and  function3 implemented to get this kind of backtrace?  Can you give me an example? (i don't have the original code).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to do, especially if you read [11.1 Inline Functions](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inline-Functions.html). Below is an example.

Source file (`inlined.cpp`). Function should actually do something useful to not be thrown away by the optimizer.

```
#include <iostream>

static void
printIt()
{
    std::cout << "Hi." << std::endl;
}

int
main(void)
{
    printIt();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with optimization and debug information:

```
g++ -g -O1 -o inline inline.cpp
```

Debug (shortened). Placing breakpoint on `printIt()` probably won't work for you too, one needs to *step into inlined function* to actually get to its body (read page linked at the top).

```
gdb ./inline
> b main
> r
> s
> s
6           std::cout << "Hi." << std::endl;
(gdb) info frame 0
Stack frame at 0x7fffffffded0:
 rip = 0x40088c in printIt (inline.cpp:6); saved rip 0x7ffff7217d85
 inlined into frame 1
 source language c++.
 Arglist at unknown address.
 Locals at unknown address, Previous frame's sp in rsp
```